# Compile GLib for i386 on OS X

Tags: c, gcc, gstreamer, configure, glib

I try to build my 32 bit i386 dylib library with some Gstreamer functions on Mac OS X using Xcode. I need to create exactly 32 bit i386 library because I will use this library from Gtk# app, but I can't build 64 bit application using Xamarin Studio. So I only can build 32 bit library and 32 bit application.

When I changed `Architectures` item in my dylib Xcode project to `32 bit Intel(i386)`, then I got error:

> /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/glibconfig.h:2:10: 'i386/glibconfig.h' file not found

Due to this error I tried to build glib from git source with these args(I got this string from `INSTALL` file):

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64" \
             CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64" \
             CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E"
```

After that I got an error. `config.log` said that:

```
//...
configure:3858: checking for gcc
configure:3885: result: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64
configure:4114: checking for C compiler version
configure:4123: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: powerpc64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
configure:4134: $? = 0
configure:4123: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 -v >&5
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: powerpc64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
configure:4134: $? = 0
configure:4123: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:4134: $? = 1
configure:4123: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:4134: $? = 1
configure:4154: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4176: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64    conftest.c  >&5
error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with this triple, see -version for the available targets.'
1 error generated.
configure:4180: $? = 1
configure:4218: result: no
configure: failed program was:
//...
```

So **how can I resolve this issue and build glib for i386 architecture on OS X** or just **how can I build 32 bit i386 dylib library with Gstreamer functions on OS X?**

Comment: I guess i686 makes more sense in this case.

Comment: @user3528438 what do you mean exactly? And will it help(because I get the error: `'i386/glibconfig.h' file not found`)?